# wait for chromium to exit before continuing a shell script

Tags: shell-script, zsh, chrome, socks

I'm trying to set up a script that I can call up easily in a WM.  The idea is to establish a socks tunnel via ssh to a known-good server and then start chromium with the appropriate environment variables...Then, wait until that instance of chromium exits and then unbind the port.  The last part is important, because if left open, the script will fail to run again because the tunnel is still up.

However, when I run it, it just establishes the connection, starts chromium and then closes the connection...It doesn't wait for Chromium to close before continuing.

I've tried adding &, && and the wait function, but I think Chromium returns something after successful execution, which is triggering my script to continue.

```
ssh -f -N -M -S ~/socket -L 4771:localhost:4771 -p 1234 foo.bar.com
chromium --proxy-server="socks://localhost:4771" &&
wait
ssh -S socket -O exit foo.bar.com
```

I'm using Arch and ZSH as my shell.

Comment: By default, `chromium` doesn't put itself in the background so you shouldn't need to worry about backgrounding and wait.  Just do the simple

    `ssh -f -N -M -S ~/socket -L 4771:localhost:4771 -p 1234 foo.bar.com ;
    /usr/bin/chromium --proxy-server="socks://localhost:4771" ;
    ssh -S socket -O exit foo.bar.com `

Comment: this results in:

Created new window in existing browser session.
Control socket connect(socket): No such file or directory

Comment: Ah... you already have a copy of `chromium` running.  There isn't a new instance of chromium in this case, and the command just instructs the existing process.   If you don't need to keep the profile settings (bookmarks, etc) then the `--temp-profile` option will allow you to create a second chromium instance.  Otherwise I'm not sure it is possible to have two instances of chromium sharing the same profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I can think of is running `pgrep` in a loop. If you have more than one chromium running, you can isolate your script in a separate PID namespace with `unshare` or `firejail`, for instance.